# resignFirstResponder with subsequent processing problems (keyboard dismiss blocked or crash on iPhone 5)

Tags: iphone, ios, thread-safety, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have the following workflow:

```
Input in Textfield -> (Return key of TextField pressed: resignFirstResponder, IBAction of Button called) -> IBAction of Button: perform an intensive operation
```

The problem is that the intensive operation is started before the Keyboard is dismissed with `resignFirstResponder`. As in other posts suggested (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452767/1685971) I tried to use:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self performSelector:@selector(ibActionMethod:) withObject:sender afterDelay:someTime];
    return YES;
}
```

This works fine in simulator or on iPhone 4 but leads to a crash running on iPhone 5 (what I cannot understand, because I didn't use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`):

```
void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool): Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool): Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

Another option I tried is to wait for resignFirstResponder in main thread with

```
[textField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

But with this the keyboard is still not dismissed immediately (probably because the method waits only for the return of the selector `resignFirstResponder` and not for the finishing of the keyboard animation.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: I don't think you mean to pass sender?

Comment: @Jonathan : Sorry, what do you mean? The sender is passed only to the IBAction - but that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // your button action
});
```

i was also facing the same error,get solved by above trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

       [textField resignFirstResponder];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //your code here

        });

       return YES;
```

}

Comment: Adding an explanation as to why this solves the problem would help make this a much better answer.

Comment: The dispatched code will not run in main thread, right? I think this is a problem for me as in the IBAction are some UI-Operations are performed...